# Selenium hanging on .click() in while loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download all of the spreadsheets from this website and the site requires me to click on the item and then click on a download button. The spreadsheets are all saved with the same id with an increasing number after each. I am trying to use a while loop to solve this problem but I am unsure if this is the best way to do this.

```
i = 0
    while i < 13:
        device = 'ctl00_LeftBarContent_lvLeftPanel_lbDevices_i' + str(i)
        deviceElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(device))
        deviceElement.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        downloadXpath = "ctl00_LeftBarContent_lvLeftPanel_btnDownload"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(downloadXpath)).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
```

Currently, the code runs up to clicking the download button, the file downloads and then it seems to hang at the button and eventually times out. I am using the chrome driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This comment is just regarding your indentation. Either indent i, or de-indent all your code after i.

Incorrect Example 'Hello World':

```
i = 0
    while i < 13:
        print 'hello world'
        i+=1
'error unexpected indent'
```

Correct Example 'Hello World':

```
i = 0
while i < 13:
    print 'hello world'
    i+=1

'Hello world'
'Hello world'
'Hello world'
'Hello world'
etc...
```

So for your problem, indent the problem correctly and retry. If you're still having issues, throw in some print statements before and after every command to see where you're getting stuck. Just a guess, but you may have to switch frames and then close the frame after the first download has completed.

Comment: add only the result first instead of providing tutorials.